# Overflow text block jumps directly to interactive element in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll

I am making an agreement page, in which there is a large body of text in a small window, followed by an "I agree" checkbox at the bottom of the scrollable window.  In theory, the user would need to scroll to the bottom of the window to be able to click the checkbox, and then would be able to continue.
However, currently I am running into the problem where, upon opening of my page to see the agreement, the window jumps immediately to the bottom of the page to the checkbox, which defeats the entire point of the page.
I suspect that the window checks if there are any interactive elements on the currently viewable content, and when it sees there aren't, it jumps the window to the nearest viewable content.
What property in angular/html/scss is making this jump happen, and how can I find/control it?

```
<p class="disclosure" id="disclosure">
  Lots of text.
  Lots of text.
  Lots of text.
  Lots of text.
  Lots of text.
  Check Here: <br> 
    <mat-checkbox (click)="toggleAgreement()"></mat-checkbox>
</p>
div class="action-buttons" >
    <button mat-button (click)="close()" class="command secondary">Cancel</button> 
    <button mat-button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!agreed" class="command primary">Agree and Submit</button>
</div>
```

```
export class ComponentName implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  agreed: boolean = false;
  variable: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ComponentName>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.scroller = document.getElementById("disclosure");
    this.scrollHeight = this.scroller.scrollHeight;
    this.scroller.scrollTo(0,0);
    console.log(this.scrollHeight);
    this.data = this.agreed;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.scroller.scrollTo(0,0);
  }

  close(): boolean {
    console.log(this.scroller.scrollTop);
    this.dialogRef.close(this.data);
    return false;
  }

  toggleAgreement(): void {
    this.agreed = !this.agreed;
  }

  submit() {
    this.data = this.agreed;
    this.close();
  }

}
```

```
.disclosure {
    color: black;
    margin-left: 8%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    height: 75%;
    width: 85%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here are some details from my own experimentation that might help guide or help anyone trying to answer my question:

- The jumping to the bottom takes place after the angular lifecycle
- The page has no interactive elements (only text) other than the check box, and a few buttons at the bottom.
- If you put a blank checkbox at the top of the page, the problem no longer exists (although this seems like a hack).
- If you disable the checkbox at the bottom of the page (via the "disabled" tool), then the problem no longer exists (suggesting something about the interactiveness being important).
- If you place something else, like an input field or a select menu, the page still jumps to it.
- If you place something like a link () then the page doesn't jump to it.
- The page clearly starts at the top, and then immediately jumps to the bottom.
- If you change the overflow styling, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, update from 3 months later, I was attempting to solve a problem with mat-dialog scrolling when I saw an **autoFocus** setting.  And yes, the small window that I was referencing above was a mat-dialog window, and the autoFocus setting is by default set to true.  So, if you have an interactive, or "focusable" as they call it, element, then a mat-dialog will instantly focus on it, perhaps even scrolling all the way down an agreement page ;).
So, in summary, if you are making an agreement page that uses a mat-dialog to access it, make sure that you toggle `autoFocus: false` in your mat-dialog options for opening that component.